# Why are the SHAP values for some features in my model always negative (or positive)?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, shap, beeswarm

I am explaining a `HistGradientBoostingRegressor` from sci-kit learn. I use the TreeExplainer from the `shap` package to get the SHAP values. My model has 48 features, some of which are strongly correlated. The beeswarm summary plot of the model looks like this:

[image]

How is it possible that the SHAP values of some features are consistently negative (or positive) and not centered at 0?

I never saw this anywhere else. Intuitively it does not make sense to me, since the model could just add a constant to avoid the shift.

Comment: This means if you observe those features you tend to obtain positive or negative outcome. This might well be due to your data input composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is often the case, formulating the question helped to discover the answer. The problem arises because i accidentally scaled the data the model was trained on in a different way than the data i passed to the explanation algorithm.

A similar question has been answered on github: https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/553